# Why won't my Workflow run on a Form library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I have an InfoPath Form library in SP Online and I cannot get SP 2013 Workflows to run on it.  I built a simple workflow that can be manually started.  It copies a date field from an item in the Form library and pastes it into a different library.  When I start it, the workflow starts, but when I look at the internal status, it says the "Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."  I get the same error even if I just try to get the workflow to send an email when an item is created or if the workflow is manually started.  Can anyone tell me what I have to do to get workflows to run on Form libraries?  Thanks.
This is the Workflow:
[image: Workflow Pic 1]
[image: Workflow pic 2]

Comment: It is hard to tell without looking at the steps and settings of your designer workflow.

Comment: are you testing with the system account?

Comment: Yes.  I'm the admin.  This only happens with a Form library.  I have lots of other Workflows that work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There was some kind of problem with the library itself.  I created a template with the content, deleted the library, then added the library back to the site.  The workflow works fine now.